# won't sound when I press the button

Tags: android, kotlin, audio

When I press a button I want it to make a sound that was located by the firebase but when I press it I don't make any sound

```
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nmixer-97a91.appspot.com/o/musics%2FDark%20World.mp3?alt=media&token=f8564ca6-cf59-468d-bd98-13ff646a1752")
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener {
                fun OnPrepared(mp:MediaPlayer) {
                    mp.start()
                }
            }
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
        }catch (e:IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: Is there any exception? If yes, please share the same.

Comment: Perhaps you should add logs to see what is getting called vs what is not and confirm that no IOException is occuring perhaps it can't access the datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your **.mp3** `URL` into `URI` and pass it to the `MediaPlayer.create()` , also do not call `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` as `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri);` is already preparing the `MediaPlayer` returned, so you cannot call prepare again, and as long as you want to stream audio you need to use `setAudioAttributes` since `setAudioStreamType` is now deprecated.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nmixer-97a91.appspot.com/o/musics%2FDark%20World.mp3?alt=media&token=f8564ca6-cf59-468d-bd98-13ff646a1752");

 btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                        new AudioAttributes
                                .Builder()
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                                .build());
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
```